Diagonalizing the metric tensor $g$
Let's call a bilinear, symmetric, non-degenerate transformation:
$$g: L\times L \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
the "metric". It belongs in the set of all symmetric bilinear transformations $\mathcal{L}_2^{(s)}(L,\mathbb{R})$ which is isomorphic with the set $S^2(L^*)$ of all symmetric, two times covariant tensors. $g$ is determined fully by its action on the basis of $L$ : $g_{ij}=g(e_i,e_j)$. Now my textbook says the following:
$$$$
There exists a basis {$e_i$} in which the components of the metric tensor are $g_{ij}=\varepsilon_i \delta_{ij}$ ($\varepsilon_{ij}=\pm 1$). Since this is given without a proof, I have two questions relating to the validity of this claim.
$$$$
First of all I want to confirm the validity of the claim about orthoganlization. The space of all homomorpfisms on $L$, Hom($L,L$) is isomorphic to the space $L\otimes L^*$ so that if we contract a vector with a tensor in that space we get a vector back. Then it would be trivial to ask about eigenvectors of such a symmetric tensor: $T^i_{\ \ j}x^j=\lambda x^i$ and orthoganlization would be trivial to prove by spectral theory. However when we are dealing with the metric tensor, it's corresponding transformation takes a vector and spits out a linear functional from the dual space:
$$g_{ij}x^j=\lambda x^*_i$$
The only way I can think of making sense of this "eigenvalue equation" is by introducing an innter product so I can use the Reisz's representation of the given functional and deal only in orthonormal bases where the basis and it's dual are the same  and then the equation becomes a true eigenvalue equation where I can orthogonalize $g$. My problem here is that I had to introduce an inner product and this should be provable only with the given information about $g$ in the beginning. Can you tell me how is that done?
$$$$
My second problem is with the normed "eigenvalues". I just can't seem to understand why a random bilinear, symmetric, non-degenerate bilinear map $g$ would have "eigenvalues" of only $1$ or $-1$. Does this have to do anything with the covariance of $g$? I have no idea.

Is $L$ finite dimensional?

Yes dim($L$)=$l$

To find an orthogonal basis for a symmetric bilinear form is simply a different problem to finding the eigenvalues of a linear map. One aspect of this is seen in the normalization of the basis vectors for example -- if $v$ is any vector with $g(v,v)\neq 0$, you can rescale $v$ by the square root of $|g(v,v)|$ to get a vector $u$ with $g(u,u) = \pm 1$, whereas an eigenvalue is unchanged by scaling the eigenvector.

A pedantic remark: sometimes in the relativity literature, you often hear “eigenvalues of the metric” but as you seem to have observed, this is complete garbage. Bilinear forms do not have eigenvalues; that’s a concept reserved for linesr maps between the same vector space (finite-dimensionality is not enough, they have to be the same vector space). The proof of the theorem you’re after is really just a variant of the Gram-Schmidt procedure, i.e it’s just a clever induction argument.

Updated: Shortened the proof of the existence of an orthogonal basis.
Notation/terminology: If $V$ is an $\mathbb R$-vector space, $g \colon V\times V \to \mathbb R$ a symmetric bilinear form, then if $X\subseteq V$ is any subset of $V$, let
$$
X^{\perp} = \{v \in V: g(v,x)=0, \forall x \in X\}.
$$
Note that $X^{\perp}$ is always a subspace of $V$. The radical $\text{rad}(g)$ of $g$ is $V^{\perp}$. The form $g$ is said to be nondegenerate if $\text{rad}(g)=\{0\}$. We say that $V$ is the orthogonal direct sum of two subspaces $U$ and $W$ and write $V = U \perp\mkern-20.7mu\bigcirc \hspace{1mm} W$, if $V = U \oplus W$ and $W \subseteq U^{\perp}$ (or equivalently $U\subseteq W^{\perp}$).
Note that, unlike what happens with inner products, if $g$ is an arbitrary symmetric bilinear form, it may well happen that its restriction $g_{|U}$ to a subspace $U$ of $V$ is degenerate even if $g$ is nondegenerate on $V$: it follows immediately from the definitions above that $\text{rad}(g_{|U}) = U\cap U^{\perp}$, and in general this intersection can be non-zero.
Theorem: If $g\colon V\times V\to \mathbb R$ is a symmetric bilinear form, then there is a basis $B=\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ such that $g(e_i,e_j)=0$ if $i\neq j$ and $g(e_i,e_i) \in \{0,\pm 1\}$.
Proof: We use induction on $\dim(V)$. If $\dim(V)=1$ then pick any nonzero vector $v\in V$ and let $r = \sqrt{|g(v,v)|}$. If $r=0$ then let $e_1=v$ while if $r>0$ let $e_1 = v/r$ so that $g(e_1,e_1)\in \{0,\pm 1\}$ as required. Now assume $\dim(V)=n>1$. If $g(v,w)=0$ for all $v,w\in V$ then $g=0$ and any basis of $V$ will suffice. If not, pick some $v,w \in L$ with $g(v,w)\neq 0$. Then since
$$
0 \neq g(v+w,v+w) = g(v,v)+2g(v,w) + g(w,w),
$$
at least one of $g(v,v),g(w,w)$ or $g(v+w,v+w)$ must be non-zero. Let $f_n$ to be such a vector, so that if $U=\mathbb R.f_n$ then $g_{|U}$ is non-degenerate, and by the $n=1$ case we may replace $f_n$ with $e_n$ where $g(e_n,e_n)=\pm 1$.
Now if $v \in V$ then
$$
v = \varepsilon_n(v,e_n).e_n+(v-\varepsilon_n(v,e_n)e_n) \in U \oplus U^{\perp}
$$
so that $V = U\oplus U^{\perp}$, and so $\dim(U^{\perp})=n-1$. Thus by induction we know there is a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1}\}$ of $U^{\perp}$ satisfying the conditions of the theorem, and hence $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ with the required property.
Since the form $g$ is assumed here to be non-degenerate, applying the above theorem to $(L,g)$ implies that there is a basis of the required form.
Note that the theorem can also be viewed as a classification of symmetric bilinear forms on a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$:
Corollary: If $V$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector space and $g\colon V\times V \to \mathbb R$ is a symmetric bilinear form, let
$$
s(g)= \max\{\dim(U): U\leq V, g_{|U} \text{ is positive definite}\}
$$
and let $r(g) = \dim(\text{rad}(g))$. Then, up to the action of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$, the form $g$ is uniquely determined by the pair of integers $(s(g),r(g))$.
Proof: Let $B$ be a basis of $V$ as given by the previous theorem, and let
$$
\begin{split}
B_+ = \{b \in B: &g(b,b)=1\}, \quad B_- = \{b \in B: g(b,b)=-1\}, \\
B_0 &= \{b \in B: g(b,b)=0\}.
\end{split}
$$
Then $B_0$ is a basis of $\text{rad}(g)$, and if we let $P=\text{span}(B_+)$ and $Q=\text{span}(B_-)$, then we may decompose $V$ into an orthogonal direct sum
$
V = P \perp\mkern-20.7mu\bigcirc \hspace{1mm} Q \perp\mkern-20.7mu\bigcirc \hspace{1mm} \text{rad}(g)
$
where $g_{|P}$ is positive-definite (i.e. an inner product), and $g_{|Q}$ is negative-definite (i.e. $-g_{|Q}$ is an inner product).
Now if $U$ is any subspace on which $g$ is positive-definite, clearly $U\cap Q\oplus \text{rad}(g)=\{0\}$, and hence
$$
\dim(U)\leq \dim(V)-\dim(Q)-\dim(\text{rad}(g)) = \dim(P).
$$
It follows that $\dim(P)=|B_+| = s(g)$ is independent of the choice of the orthogonal basis $B$. Since $|B_0|=r(g)$ and $|B_-| = |B|-|B_+|-|B_0|$, it follows that if $g_1,g_2$ are two symmetric bilinear forms with $s(g_1)=s(g_2)$ and $r(g_1)=r(g_2)$, then if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are bases of $V$ which are orthogonal for $g_1$ and $g_2$ respectively, we can pick a bijection $\psi\colon B_1\to B_2$ such that if $b_1 \in B_1$ then $g_1(b_1,b_1) = g_2(\psi(b_1),\psi(b_1))$ and hence if $\varphi\colon V\to V$ is the linear map extending $\psi$ we have $g_2 = g_1(\varphi(v),\varphi(w))$ for all $v,w \in V$, that is, $g_1$ and $g_2$ are equivalent under the action of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$.
Addendum: A symmetric bilinear form $g\colon V\times V \to \mathbb R$ can be viewed as a tensor in $(V\otimes V)^* = V^*\otimes V^*$ (assuming $\dim(V)<\infty$). Now $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W) \cong V^*\otimes W$ (again assuming $\dim(V)<\infty$) so one may associate to $g$ a linear map $\phi\colon V\to V^*$, which, explicitly, is given by $v \mapsto \phi(v)$ where $\phi(v)(w) = g(v,w)$. Since $\phi$ has different domain and range, you cannot seek eigenvector for $\phi$ however. What an orthogonal basis for the form corresponds to is finding a basis of $V$ which is mapped (up to sign) to its dual basis.

But by including the orthogonal complement, you are suggesting an inner product. Can't this be done without $L$ being a Hilbert space but just regular vector space?

I've added a couple of paragraphs to the start of my answer to clarify this, but no, it does not assume that the symmetric bilinear form $g$ is an inner products, the notation $U^{\perp}$ indicates the "orthogonal subspace" but that does not in general have to be a complement.
